# Create a full screen slideshow with jquery

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fullscreen

I'm trying to create a simple full screen slideshow, i know you can get plugins but i'm trying to learn jquery and i want to make it from scratch.

I want the images to be located in style.css.

Here's my very simple html code:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu-logo"></div>
  </div><!-- /.menu-wrapper -->

  <div class="main-view-wrapper slide">
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
  </div><!-- /.main-view-wrapper -->
</div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->
```

Here's the current css code:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html,body {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#page-wrapper {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
} 
.main-view-wrapper {
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
.carousel-wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: url(http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/G-MerryXmasScienceLrg.gif) no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

And here's a current fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2wu5H/3/

I've not got any query yet as i don't know where to start

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating slideshow - Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238393/creating-slideshow-jquery)

Comment: i think you can refer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238393/creating-slideshow-jquery?rq=1

Comment: you could see how other plugins work and try to get your inspiration from there. This is a way to learn jquery

Comment: Thanks guys, I already looked at that but I wanted my images coming from the stylesheet and not the html

Answer (score 0):

using settimeout function to change the class:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

for more please read: [Basic setTimeout() Example](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/)

but better way is that define your image to the html page

also you can use `JQuery Cycle` for that:

[JQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/)